# I am trying to identify this little "bug"

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am trying to identify a bug. I find this little guy in Paris, at the rooftop near plants, in the streets without plants. I let one on my t-shirt, and it was trying to unpick it. I took a picture :

[image]

I think remembering having seen such bugs in old closets, on clothes, when I was kid, but I am not sure.

Comment: The focus isn't the best, but it looks to me like a lace bug (order Hemiptera, family Tingidae); not knowing the French fauna forbids further depth from me.